# Set jwk-set-uri for Oauth2 resource server at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot application which is configured as a oauth2ResourceServer in the Spring Security config.

This configuration requires the following entry in the application.properties file:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/devrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

so that Spring Security can verify the JWT signatures.

The actual implementation works fine, however, I'm having hard time writing the tests. For my tests I use a test Keycloak instance running in a docker container, started by the relevant test using TestContainers. Since the port of the test keycloak changes all the time I cannot set the `jwk-set-uri` in advance. The actual jwk-set-uri can only be set once the keycloak container started.

So the question is: How could I set or change the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri` property at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The `jwk-set-uri` can be configured at runtime in your WebSecurityConfig. This takes precedence over any configuration property.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DirectlyConfiguredJwkSetUri {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                    .jwkSetUri("https://idp.example.com/.well-known/jwks.json")
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Source:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.0-RC1/reactive/oauth2/resource-server.html#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-jwt-jwkseturi-dsl